# Can you explicitly enter a method's return value in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

Assume I have the following Rails models and the method shown is tested.

```ruby
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs

  def total_annual_income
    jobs.collect { |j| j.annual_salary}.sum
    # Or some other AR magic to do it directly in the database; doesn't matter
  end
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  # property :annual_salary

  belongs_to :employee
end
```

Now, assume that I'm going to write some other method elsewhere that calls `Employee#total_annual_income`.  When I test this method with FactoryGirl, is it possible to set up my `Employee` factories directly with a `total_annual_income` property without having to make corresponding `Job` factories?  I.e., can I simply do

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee1, class: Employee do
    id 100
    total_annual_income 100000.0
  end
end
```

instead of

```ruby
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee1, class: Employee do
    id 100
  end
end

# WANT TO OMIT THIS ENTIRE SET OF FACTORIES #
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee1_job1, class: Job do
    id 100
    employee_id 100
    annual_salary 60000.0
  end
  factory :employee1_job2, class: Job do
    id 101
    employee_id 100
    annual_salary 40000.0
  end
end
# WANT TO OMIT THIS ENTIRE SET OF FACTORIES #
```

I'm kinda new to FactoryGirl still, so apologies if I've overlooked something basic.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Associations information under the Factory Girl documentation:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations

This has an example of `:user_with_posts` which uses `#create_list` to generate a list of posts for a user - a bit like your list of jobs. Since on StackOverflow it is customary to include full answers in case an external link should become broken, here's copypasta of the example with its comments:

> Generating data for a has_many relationship is a bit more involved, depending on the amount of flexibility desired, but here's a surefire example of generating associated data.

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  # post factory with a `belongs_to` association for the user
  factory :post do
    title "Through the Looking Glass"
    user
  end

  # user factory without associated posts
  factory :user do
    name "John Doe"

    # user_with_posts will create post data after the user has been created
    factory :user_with_posts do
      # posts_count is declared as a transient attribute and available in
      # attributes on the factory, as well as the callback via the evaluator
      transient do
        posts_count 5
      end

      # the after(:create) yields two values; the user instance itself and the
      # evaluator, which stores all values from the factory, including transient
      # attributes; `create_list`'s second argument is the number of records
      # to create and we make sure the user is associated properly to the post
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:post, evaluator.posts_count, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> This allows us to do:

```
create(:user).posts.length # 0
create(:user_with_posts).posts.length # 5
create(:user_with_posts, posts_count: 15).posts.length # 15
```

The core of this is really that `#create_list` method shown above.

[EDIT] *Completely* untested, I think your example becomes something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee_with_jobs, class: Employee do
    id 100

    transient do
      jobs_count 2
    end

    after(:create) do |employee, evaluator|
      create_list(:job, evaluator.jobs_count,
                  employee: employee,
                  annual_salary: 40000.0)
    end
  end
end

create(:employee_with_jobs, jobs_count: 5) # Expecting total salary 200000.0.
```

...more or less.